# XML Editor for Linux via SSH access?

Tags: xml, linux, editor, ssh

I need to edit XML files on a small Linux box that we have created. We have only SSH access on theses boxes. Is there a dedicated XML editor, or a configuration for Vim/Emacs to edit XML easily, with integrated XSD validation?

I found some tutorials for Vi
http://oss.sgi.com/LDP/HOWTO/Vim-HOWTO/xml_editor.html
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_as_XML_Editor
http://www.pinkjuice.com/howto/vimxml/

Regards,
Cédric

Comment: If all your other boxes are Windows, you can try http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/ to mount your Linux drive over ssh (with sshfs) and edit using your Windows tools. There are equivalent libraries available for Mac (search for 'ssfhs' or 'fuse').

Comment: We have a lot of boxes and we use severals Windows/Linux PC to work, so disk mount may not be easy to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs has XML support out of the box via the PSGML mode.  It supports DTD validation, auto tag closing, sytax-coloring, etc.

I have used another package though, called nXML, because I needed schema support.

http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode

Answer (score 1):

Emacs with tramp extension is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

vim should recognise the xml syntax if you switch highlighting on. Otherwise, as XML is plain text, you can quite happily edit with vim or vi -- but with no syntax checks.

If you have ssh running you should be able to use the secure copy command "scp" to move the file to and from your local machine edit it with your favourate tool.

Comment: we often open a lot of file, so scp/sftp is not an easy solution

Comment: Worth looking at "Winscp" then. Make the remote directory look like a local folder on your windows box.